# How to connect php application to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have created register form using php and validation done by using jquery.

I have files are `index.php`, `submit.php` and `functions.php`.

So i need to create `config.php` to connect database.

I have done to create table in **phpmyadmin** and created `config.php`.

Here is my config.php:

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "crop";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO crop (fname,lname,email,pass,phone,img,sex-select,dob) VALUES (:sas,:asas,:asafs)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
?>
```

I am not sure this code correct or not? And i don't know how to include in existing my php files.

I am new to php and now i am learning, can you please help me out to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so whats your question? how to run this code? or how to include it in another file? or are you getting any errors

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: from this code, i didn't get connect to database

Comment: Use try ... catch block, when you are connecting to the DB. Maybe, there is an error: wrong credentials or MySQL server is down.

Comment: where to i include config.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include the connection in other files you simply need to add the following near the top of the other file, before you need any database connection:

```
require_once 'config.php';
```

**require** generates a fatal error if the file is not found and **require_once** guarantees that the file will only be included once even though you call it multiple times. Since your application will probably not work without a database connection you want the fatal error to let you know that the file wasn't found and it's highly unlikely that you'll want more than one database connection.

There are also **include** and **include_once** but in this case you'll want to avoid these because they don't stop the script if the config file isn't found.

PHP documentation:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: index.php or submit.php should include config.php, not the other way around, like I said, you want to include it near the top of the index.php or submit.php file. Most likely at the very top:

<?php
require_once 'config.php';

Comment: You need to do a PDOStatement::execute() on the data, in your code you have already prepared the statement $q so you need to bind the data to the parameters and execute it. You can do it with a simple array like this:

$values = array(':sas' => $sas, ':asas' => $asas, ':asafs' => $asafs');
$q->execute($values);

Comment: BTW - your insert/update code should NOT be in the config.php file but in submit.php after you include config.php. Anything after the $conn = ... statement should be moved.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print the results of the query that you ran.

[Check Here on PDO: Prepared Statement](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Prepared-Statement-P550.html)

Comment: i am asking how to connect database man?.. still i didn't connect. when i enter input details, it will need to store in database.

Comment: You have to explain what happens now when you Submit the values from your submit.php? Does it give an error? If so what is it? Be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this connection code in your web application, your config.php look like

```
<?php
$Db_host = "localhost";
$Db_user = "root";                     //DB User name
$Db_name = "crop";                    //DB name
$Db_password = "";                   //DB password if you have
$cnn=mysql_pconnect($Db_host,$Db_user,$Db_password) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

and after that you can call this file with the help of include or require function in your page.

your submit.php looks like this

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>
```

Comment: I am asking where to include config.php whether index.php or submit.php?

Comment: on which page you want to connect your database, just call the config.php on that particular page.

for example : if you want to update/insert/delete something in atabase on submit.php then you add to only submit.php